# Probability about $\sigma$-field generated by infinite ranges

Tags: probability, measure-theory

> Let $\Omega = [0,1]$. Let $$S=\{[0,1]\} \cup \left\{\left[\frac {1}{2^{n+1}},\frac {1}{2^n}\right) : n=0,1,2\ldots\right\}.$$ Let $F_s$ be the $\sigma$-field generated by $S$, that is the smallest $\sigma$-field that contains $S$. Which of the following events belong to $F_s$?
>
> a) $\{0\}$
>
> b) $\{1\}$
>
> c) $\{\frac {1}{2}\}$
>
> e) $\{0,1\}$
>
> f) $(\frac{1}{4},1]$
>
> g) $[0,\frac {1}{2}]$
>
> h)$[\frac{1}{4},1)$

I figured easily how the complement of union of everything inside would give (e). However, I just can't figure out if either of $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$ can also be in the field . Also, explanation on the other ones would be really helpful.

Comment: I noticed you haven't accepted an answer for any of the questions you've asked.  Please do so if we've answered your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I believe your $S$ should be $\{[0, 1]\}\cup$ instead of $[0, 1]\cup$.
2. {0} or {1} by itself are not in the field.  Because the only set that contains either of them already contains both of them.  So any time a union or whatever contains one, it would contain the other as well.  For this reason, (f) and (g) are not in the field either.
3. Based on this technique, you should be able to figure out the answer to (c).
4. (h) should be really easy.